# how to remove Native-Base actionSheet default paddingY?

Tags: react-native, native-base, actionsheet

I have an actionsSheet and in actionSheet.content use an fullscreen image as a child but actionSheet don't let me make this image fullscreen.

I tried `padding={0}` or `margin={0}` but now working.
and also set `resizeMode="cover"` for the image.

[example Image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxFvu.png)